# Why requests raise_for_status() not called using pytest

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

There is a class and a method `_get_authorize_token`

```
    class StsAPI:
    
        def _get_authorize_token(self) -> str:
            try:
                resp = requests.post(settings.AUTHORIZATION_SERVICE_URL, json=self.data)
                print(resp.status_code)
                resp.raise_for_status()
                result = resp.json()
            except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
                raise Exception('Not authorized')
            return result.get('token', {})

sts_api = StsAPI()
```

And a test case for `_get_authorize_token`

```
def test_raise_exception_if_request_error(
    requests_mock,
    mocker
):
    requests_mock.return_value = mocker.Mock(status_code=500)
    client = sts_api
    with pytest.raises(Exception, match='Not authorized'):
        client._get_authorize_token()

@pytest.fixture
def requests_mock(mocker):
    return mocker.patch('project.logic.connector.requests.post')
```

Test result

```
>       with pytest.raises(Exception, match='Not authorized'):
E       Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'Exception'>
```

the `print(resp.status_code)` line returns status **500**. Based on this I assume `raise_for_status` should give an error.

If  change the logic to

```
def _get_authorize_token(self) -> str:
    resp = requests.post(settings.AUTHORIZATION_SERVICE_URL, json=self.data)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception('Not authorized')
    return resp
```

Then the test is successful

Comment: You mocked the response; you aren't calling the original `raise_for_status` now, so no exception is raised.

Comment: But if I don't lock requests.post, the external service will be called, and this shouldn't happen. What do I do?

Comment: See my answer. Mocks, however, are easy to overuse and often not the best solution. You might try a library like `vcr`, which can intercept a plain HTTP request and provide a canned response instead of trying to connect to a remote host. (`vcr` also lets you capture a real response from a remote service to help build up a suite of responses to use for later tests.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mocked the response, accessing the `raise_for_status` attribute simply returns a new mock, rather than getting the actual `raise_for_status` method of a real response. Just like you configured the mock to produce a `status_code` of 500, you need to configure it to produce a method that raises the exception you expect on a status code of 500. Something like

```
def _raise_exception(*args):
    raise HTTPError()

requests_mock.return_value = mocker.Mock(status_code=500, raise_for_status=_raise_exception)
```

Now when your code-under-test calls `resp.raise_for_status`, your `_raise_exception` function will be called.